How can I flag posts which have been vandalized by their OP?
I'm assuming as a result of the announcement with OpenAI, users are removing content from their previous questions and answers. I just flagged one as requiring moderator intervention, but I am wondering if that is the correct action to take. I took a quick look through previous meta questions, but I only see a couple mentioning it, and the comments just resolve them there.
I'm thinking we may see a bit more of this in the near future and would like to clarify the best way to handle them as a community member.

Mod flagging is the correct way to do it

@Zoe thanks for your response. I did see your response to my flag as well before I posted, but I figured if I had the question it might be worthwhile to ask it here to clarify for other users. Thanks!
